# How to measure the temperature inside a combustion chamber

Tags: temperature, measurement, combustion-chamber

This question is inspired by [How do you determine what the temperature will be in the combustion chamber of a rocket engine?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/34679/how-do-you-determine-what-the-temperature-will-be-in-the-combustion-chamber-of-a) .
 I wonder how you would mesaure the temperature on the inner surface of the combustion chamber.

My first guess would be a contact-free method such as infrared cameras, but that would involve a lot of noise from the flow.

Comment: about IR measurement; noise can be averaged, and a two-wavelength ratiometric method might be better than just a broadband bolometric measurement.

Comment: A [pyrometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrometer) may be used but there are problems when measuring hot gases, small solids within the hot gas are needed.