# Chamber pressure of a gas pressure fed liquid rocket motor

Tags: liquid-fuel, pressure, pressure-fed-engine

I am studying rocketry and am currently learning about pump fed vs gas pressure fed propulsion systems.

Upon reading about gas pressure systems, I googled the formula to find the chamber pressure for gas pressure fed systems but did not find the formula.  What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no simple equation to calculate the chamber pressure.

One major complication is that the chamber temperature depends on the chemical reaction rate of the propellants, which is a function of the temperature, making it an iterative process. See [How do you determine what the temperature will be in the combustion chamber of a rocket engine?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/34679/how-do-you-determine-what-the-temperature-will-be-in-the-combustion-chamber-of-a/34681)

Sutton, 4th edition, p.181 sums up the process as follows

> The combustion chamber conditions (such as chamber temperature and gas
>   composition) can be calculated by using the conditions of mass balance
>   (Equation 6-9), the pressure balance (Equation 6-10), several chemical
>   equilibrium conditions (Equation 6-8), and the energy balance
>   (Equation 6-11) and by simultaneously solving these equations (see
>   Reference 6-2, 6-3, or 6-4). The assumptions listed in Chapter 3 for
>   an ideal rocket apply here also. Complete combustion is postulated,
>   that is, all the propellant is reacted into suitable products, The
>   materials introduced as propellant are transformed adiabatically and
>   irreversibly to certain presumed reaction product constituents in the
>   amounts fixed by equilibrium coefficients, total pressure, and mass
>   balance at a temperature fixed by the available energy of reaction.
>   The unknowns in these equations are the chamber temperature T, and the
>   molar fractions n, of each of the f constituents in the reaction
>   product gases: thus the number of independent equations must equal f +
>   1.

This process is fundamentally the same regardless of whether the engine is pump- or pressure-fed.