# Combustion chamber pressure calculation

Tags: rockets, engines, engine-design

A liquid propellent rocket engine: how is combustion chamber pressure calculated? Is it the different between turbopump outlet pressure and the drop in the injectors (losses aside)? Thanks!

Comment: Consider searching the site before posting. Your question is a duplicate of https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/37123/chamber-pressure-of-a-gas-pressure-fed-liquid-rocket-motor and  [How is chamber pressure determined for rocket engines?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/21758/how-is-chamber-pressure-determined-for-rocket-engines)

Comment: Oooops, you are right, thank you!

Comment: The answers on that question were quite bad, I have added a better answer.